# How do I instantiate a class with a constructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

I want to be able to run my `RunApp` method with my `StartUp` class in my Console App with a `static` `void` `Main` method. The problem is that I use dependency injection in `StartUp` class with a constructor to make an instance with other classes with methods. But I do not know how to proceed so I can use my RunApp method inside static void Main.

I have tried to use

```cs
StartUp s = new StartUp();
s.RunApp();
```

But it does not seem to work, I have to have parameters to enter.

**StartUp Class**:

```cs
public class StartUp : IStartUp
{
    private readonly AddCustomer _addCustomer;
    private readonly Booking _booking;
    private readonly GetCustomer _getCustomer;
    private readonly Service _service;

    public StartUp(
        AddCustomer addCustomer,
        Booking booking,
        GetCustomer getCustomer,
        Service service)
    {
        _addCustomer = addCustomer;
        _booking = booking;
        _getCustomer = getCustomer;
        _service = service;
    }

    public void RunApp()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Hi! Welcome to Kennel GoldenRetriver. What would you like to do?");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 1 to register a new customer and dog");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 2 to show all customers");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 3 to get all dogs");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 4 to show customers and thier related dogs");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 5 to leave dog on service");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 6 to show all dogs on service");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 7 to get your dog from service");

        bool isNumber = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int start);

        if (isNumber)
        {
            switch (start)
            {
                case 1:
                    _addCustomer.AddCustomers();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    _getCustomer.GetCustomers();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    _getCustomer.GetDogs();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    _getCustomer.GetRelatedCustomerToDog();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    _booking.AddBooking();
                    _service.AddService();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    _service.AddService();
                    break;
                case 7:
                    _service.DeleteFromService();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter valid number");
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
        }
    }
}
```

**My Main Method**

```cs
class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StartUp s = new StartUp();
        s.RunApp();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to use dependency injection, you have to commit to it at any time. You could create the dependencies by yourself (instantiate all the classes by the same rules) and pass them to the constructor. How else do you expect the class to operate properly without resolving the dependencies manually?

Comment: Where exactly does your Dependency Injection get setup? If you add your services to the service collection before instantiating `StartUp` and calling `RunApp`, you can simply retrieve the the `StartUp` class from the service provider and use that instance to call `RunApp`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My idea is that I should instantiate all my classes I need in StartUp. And this is where I use Dependecy Injection to be able to reach all functions and be able to use them. Then i only want to be able to run RunApp in the Static Void Main method so that I can run the program itself.

Comment: DI is a bit of an umbrella term that might cause some confusion because what we used to call an IoC container whose responsibility was to satisfy dependencies by injecting them has kinda disappeared and we just refer to it as DI now, the IoC/injector's presence being hidden. What you have arranged is indeed a DI setup in that a StartUp has dependencies that are injected (via the constructor) but there doesn't appear to be any IoC setup and you don't appear to inject them manually in your own code. To this end I expect your question will cause some puzzling. Perhaps explain what DI means to you

Comment: and what you plan to do to satisfy the various classes' needs for their dependencies. In short, if you aren't going to create and supply the parameters to go structure yourself you need to install and use a device that will do it for you- castle Windsor, ninject, Microsoft's DI etc (or write your own, though not sure why you would)

Comment: Thank you @CaiusJard What I think of when I use DI is that I want to use functions from other classes in my StartUp class. To do that, I have used DI. I would like to say that for me, DI is a way to instantiate classers with objects. Am I thinking right?

Comment: @Daniel have a read of this https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subject class needs to have all its dependencies satisfied in order for it to be initialized as desired.

So either provide them via [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/)

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        //...assuming the dependencies don't have dependencies themselves.
        AddCustomer addCustomer = new();
        Booking booking = new();
        GetCustomer getCustomer = new();
        Service service = new();
        
        StartUp s = new StartUp(addCustomer, booking, getCustomer, service);
        s.RunApp();
    }
}
```

or via an Inversion of Control (IoC) container that will do the heavy lifting of initializing and injecting all the registered dependencies for you.

*Simple example using default .Net Core container*

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        IServiceProvider services = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddTransient<AddCustomer>()
            .AddTransient<Booking>()
            .AddTransient<GetCustomer>()
            .AddTransient<Service>()
            .AddTransient<StartUp>()
            .BuildServiceProvider();
        
        StartUp s = services.GetService<StartUp>();
        s.RunApp();
    }
}
```

In the overly simplified Pure DI example, if any of those dependencies have explicit dependencies, then those too need to be satisfied so that all requirements are available when initializing the subject type.

The choice is yours depending on the complexity and size of the program.

Comment: Thanks that was the answer I was looking for!:). However, inside my GetCustomer I use Ef core and then use a DI like I do in my StartUp to be able to reach the Database. I get an error message when I use example 2. Where it says

"Unable to resolve service for type 'KennelProgram.Data.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'KennelProgram.New.GetCustomer'."

Should I bring something more for it to work?

Comment: You will need to `AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>` to the container so it knows how to resolve the context Read up here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0#entity-framework-contexts